# image does not want to be updated if the other values are not changed

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller

I want to update the user image but the user image will only be updated if other values are also updated, such as name/username, I have tried various ways, even though in the edit post section there is no problem

so this is my form

```
  <form action="/profile/{{ auth()->user()->id }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @method('put') 
                            @csrf
                            <label for="">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}">
        
                            <label for="">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ auth()->user()->username }}">
                            
                            
                            <label for="">Profile Picture</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image">
                            
                            <button type="submit">Update</button>
                        </form>
```

my web route

`Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('auth');`

my ProfileController

```
 $rules = [
        'name' =>  ['required', 'max:15'],
        'username' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:12', 'unique:users'],
        'image' => ['nullable','image','file','max:1024'],
    ];

    $validatedData = $request->validate($rules);

    
    if($request->file('image')) {
        if($user->image){
            Storage::delete($user->image);
        }

        $validatedData['image'] = $request->file('image')->store('profile-images');

    }
    
    $user->update($validatedData);

    return back();
```

I have tried several ways and I have also created an edit post feature and it works well, I tried to copy and paste the code and change a little from the edit post feature but it doesn't work, the image is only updated if the other values are also edited / updated, what I want is that the image is updated even if the others are not updated, thank you

Comment: Can you add a dummy field to the request, that you don't care about it's value, injecting to it any random value?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to the browser cache history.
Browsers usually store image data in cache. So if the image name is the same it won't be updated.
So I solved this problem like this.
All image names contain a unique random string with extension + ?
ex:Lynn.jpg?33f3r3